# The Statusbar does not work with false headerShown

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

I am using StatusBar it works fine but when I removed header from react-navigation it stops working. What am I doing wrong?

I am facing this issue on IOS.

```
<StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor={colors.ICE_BLUE} />
<Tab.Screen name="Wallet" component={WalletScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
```

Comment: Hi did you find a solution in the end? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SafeAreaView` Component in your `WalletScreen`.

Comment: I did but nothing happened

 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor={colors.ICE_BLUE} />

Comment: Make sure you pass `flex: 1` in style prop of `SafeAreaView` and add `translucent` prop to true in `StatusBar` like: <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" translucent={true} backgroundColor=colors.ICE_BLUE />

Comment: also tried with these changes.